# startActivity() to launch in connected Secondary Display not working as expected

Tags: android, display, android-10.0

I have a samsung s10e with Android 10. I connected my external monitor to my s10e and It worked as expected.

I have an app and want to open some activities in secondary screen if connected.

Here is the method I used to start the activity in secondary screen.

```
 private fun startActivityInSecondaryDisplay(intent: Intent) {
    val displays = activity.getSystemService(DisplayManager::class.java)?.displays
    val secondaryDisplay = displays?.get(1) // choosing secondary display
    val secondaryDisplayId = secondaryDisplay?.displayId
    val am = context.getSystemService(Context.ACTIVITY_SERVICE) as ActivityManager
    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q && secondaryDisplayId != null && am.isActivityStartAllowedOnDisplay(context, secondaryDisplayId, intent)) {
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_MULTIPLE_TASK or Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        val options = ActivityOptions.makeBasic().setLaunchDisplayId(secondaryDisplayId)
        startActivity(intent, options.toBundle())
        L.toast(context,"starting activity in display#$secondaryDisplayId")
        //code reaches here while testing on my Samsung s9 while connected
    } else {
        startActivity(intent)
    }
}
```

---

I get the following error in logcat while starting a activity.

[image]

Comment: None of those messages seem related to your app, and none are a part of a stack trace.

Comment: Yes it is related. I was trying to open a url in chrome app in secondary display with displayId (8).